# How to cache data to use in a dashboard page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

in my application, after user logs in, he is redirect to a dashboard page, that it can return every time during his session.
The data in this page will not change during this time, so I need to cache it somehow.

Is Rails responsible for this to me, or I need to do it manually?

For now, my dashboard display, among others, this search:

```
#how many men?
@men = Horario.joins(:paciente).
    where(:data => Date.today).
    where(pacientes: {sexo: MASCULINO}).count

@total = Horario.where(:data => Date.today).count
@women = @total - @men
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd use [fragment caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching) for the dashboard part.

Comment: It does not seems to work in my case. All querys are executed over and over.

Comment: The problem is that my dashboard page receive some json objects from controller and use them to build charts using javascript.